# Apparent FPS drop despite clear CPU usage drop in profile window

Tags: unity

I have an unusual performance drop (or visual choppiness) that isn't showing in the profile window at all like I'd expect.

When using Vegetation Studio Pro and AQUAS together, I get what *looks like* a serious FPS drop when I look up at the sky (away from terrain) or back down at the terrain.

However, the moment always coincides with a major drop in CPU usage (seen in the following pic). I've never seen performance issues like *drop cpu usage* - usually they appear as major spikes, reaching *higher* (meaning lower FPS) on this chart.

[image]

I'm not used to the newer Unity profile window, so I may be missing some obvious clues, but what could cause such a perceived FPS drop when the cpu usage drops?

Why does the VSync category seem to disappear for a period of time?

I'm unable to reproduce the effects when I turn off VSPro or AQUAS. Whatever the real cause is, it seems related to them being used together. I don't see any indication of the same issue when I use them individually.

Edit1: The issue goes away when I disable the Caustics system in AQUAS. It's a projector system. I still don't understand what specific issue the profiler is communicating to me.

Comment: Can you show us the visual choppiness you're observing?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/0alAO2b.gifv - Hard to show. I'm moving the mouse at a slow consistent rate. Everything is smooth until I look up. At a certain point, the camera view lags a bit then suddenly catches up to where it should be based on my input. It looks a lot like an "FPS drop" but it always coincides with that CPU drop in my profile screenshot. When I disable the AQUAS Caustics projectors, the issue goes away.

Comment: With no idea what VSPro or AQUAS do (sure, I googled, but I haven't seen any code), it's hard to tell. But a CPU drop at an FPS drop usually means threads are waiting for eachother (maybe they use the same resource?) Could you share a screenshot of the same window, but focused on the problem? Perhaps the bottom panel shows which thread is waiting, and what it is waiting for